# Make React Site with Admin Privilege's

Tags: reactjs

So, this might be a rookie question but I've never experienced how to do it. I want to create a site using React that doesn't have a DB or Backend, just a simple Frontend, but allows someone to have "admin" privileges if they want to add or remove images (it's for an artists portfolio). Is there a way to make a certain route (e.g websiteexample.com/admin) allow someone to enter a password and then have access to adding / removing files? TIA !

Comment: Look into Firebase. That will guide you out.

Comment: You technically can, though it won't be very secure.You would have to hard code the authentication logic and credentials in the front end code. So someone could look through the front end code and find those, then get admin access. So it's possible to make a site that blocks things off based on a purely front end login, though it wouldn't be secure